# send ipv6 jumbograms in c (linux) : How to change packet headers

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ipv6

I am sorry if the question is too naive, but I am confused. I want to send `IPv6 jumbograms` (to be able to multicast packets of size > 64 KB). I have been able to multicast normal IPv6 UDP packets successfully. 
For sending jumbograms, from `RFC 2675`, I get that I have to make the following changes :

1. set payload length to 0
2. set next header to hop-by-hop

But, I don't get how to implement these in `c socket programming` (which function calls to make etc.). Do I have to create a custom header or are there functions like `sendto` available to send jumbograms?

Comment: You do realize that you would need a complete path that can support an MTU that large? IPv6 can't be fragmented along the path the way IPv4 can. The sending host is responsible to pre-fragment the IPv6 packets to meet the smallest MTU in the path.

Comment: yes, I do. I am mostly concerned with how to at least assemble and send the packet successfully. Not able to send large packets because of MTU restrictions is a different thing.

Answer (score 0):

You could use raw sockets if you are making your own headers. For more information, type `man -s7 raw` or [look here](http://linux.die.net/man/7/raw). Note you will effectively need to implement your own IP stack that way.

However, my understanding is that linux itself supports IPv6 jumbograms natively so you don't need to bother. Try `ifconfig lo mtu 100000` and do some tests over the loopback device to check.

I suspect the issue might be that your network adaptor and everything on the path (end to end) needs to support the jumbograms too.

Comment: Thanks! So, if I don't want to use raw packets and use native linux support for IPv6 jumbograms, are you suggesting to try sending the packet (of larger size) in the same way (by using the sendto function and without any adjustment to the packet header)?

Comment: AIUI Linux automatically supports IPv6 jumbograms (and will set the packet header correctly), so just use `sendto` or whatever, having set the mtu correctly. However, it will only actually work if the interface and traffic path support them.

Comment: yes, it is clear to me that it will only work if the interface and traffic support is available. I hope to capture the packets at the sender using tcpdump (so that I know that the send works at least).