# UDP Socket Jumbograms in C

Tags: c, sockets, udp, ipv6

Can anybody provide a working example of what's needed to configure a UDP socket for IPv6 jumbograms? I haven't been able to find any examples of how to do this. I've tried to force IPV6 with IPV6_V6ONLY, and also set the IPV6_HOPOPTS flag, but the latter gives me an error "Invalid Argument". General idea / pseudocode follows:

```
int value = 1;
int sock = socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_V6ONLY, &value, sizeof(int));
setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_HOPOPTS, &value, sizeof(int)); // fails
```

**Update:** further reading indicates I may not need to set IPV6_HOPOPTS if I just want to send and receive jumbograms without reading them via cmsg. This post ([send ipv6 jumbograms in c (linux) : How to change packet headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32685846/send-ipv6-jumbograms-in-c-linux-how-to-change-packet-headers#comment53253667_32703681) ) suggests that it should be possible to send them just by setting the MTU on the interface higher. I tried that, but receive a "Message too long" error from sendto(), even though the data length is less than the MTU size I set on the interface. Do I need to configure the socket with anything special to be able to send jumbograms?

Comment: It's not a good idea to send UDP with more than about 576 bytes. UDP packets will be lost, and the more you put in them, the more you lose when a packet goes missing. Also, the MTU on an interface is dependent on the data-link protocol on the interface. For ethernet, it is 1500 bytes.

Comment: You haven't specified what platform you're working on.  This matters, because the protocols and options supported are platform-dependent.  On Linux, however, the UDP protocol implementation performs MTU discovery by default, and attempts to send a UDP datagram larger than that supported on the path to the specified destination are rejected with `EMSGSIZE`.  That sounds like what has happened to you.

Comment: Linux, specifically Ubuntu 14.04. For starters, I've been testing against the IPv6 loopback interface, which still fails with that error.

Comment: Note in particular that use of UDP jumbograms requires *every node on the path* from sender to receiver to support them, not only in the sense of understanding the relevant protocol details, but also in the sense of being configured with and physically capable of supporting an MTU larger than 65575.  You're highly unlikely to be in that situation unless your traffic stays entirely within a network environment under your control, and if it does, then you still have to make sure everything is configured to support it.

Comment: Yes, this is for a controlled, project-specific network.

Comment: Hm, from the comments I sense some confusion. Jumbograms are designed to exceed the IP MTU of 65535, the interface mtu is not relevant here, only in the sense, that jumbogram packets may not be fragmented, so using them with smaller mtus is usually not sensible.

Comment: I am entirely prepared to admit some confusion, @Ctx, but my understanding, supported by the material I've read so far, is that although Jumbograms work around limits in the UDP and TCP header formats used in IPv6, they also require link-layer support.  [RFC 2675](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2675) seems to say this, for example.  The point being that Jumbograms serve no purpose if they are going to be fragmented.

Comment: That is also the understanding presented in [this (non-peer-reviewed) paper](https://www.os3.nl/_media/2011-2012/courses/lia/yannick_scheelen_jeffrey_bosma_-_ipv6_jumbograms.pdf), which concludes (I paraphrase liberally) that Jumbograms seemed like a good idea at the time, but turned out to be a dead end.  The paper seems to have been the result of an academic project, so YMMV.

Comment: Additionally, I note that a patch appears to have gone into Linux kernel 3.14.5 (April, 2014) that limited the IPv6 MTU to at most 65575 bytes, regardless of link (previously it had a higher limit, I guess 4GB).  I invested some effort into finding documentation of that having since been reversed, without success.  I certainly might have missed something, but unless I did, any protocol-level support for jumbograms in that and subsequent kernels is moot -- Linux will not support an IPv6 MTU that would cause jumbograms to be used.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Good find, looks like linux doesn't support these. Maybe with raw sockets and handcrafted packets.

Comment: Thanks folks, this has been informative. Guess that explains why I couldn't find much documentation on the subject, aside from the RFCs.